# Facebook app for Windows phone 7

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I have just started learning windows phone 7 programming and working on a project. I just wanted to know any useful guides,websites,links to learn about creating facebook app (normal app to check and update statuses,photos etc.) for windows phone 7.

Can anyone point me to the right direction please ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an SDK for integrating Facebook in C#.NET based applications: [URL](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).